# Fetch data from a json instead of an Array Angular 5

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I'm new in Angular, I am making an app in Angular 5 to show images with information relative to the image, the app has a thumbnails page an when you click you can see the image with a description or a video, I'm fetching all the data from a service and an array inside the service but I need to change and instead of fetch the data from the array I need to do it from a JSON but keeping all the functionality I already have, but when I fetch the data from the JSOM I just cant see the information of image when I click.

This is the service with the array I need to change for JSON:

```
export class ArticulosService {
enter code here @Injectable()
export class ArticulosService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

visibleImages = [];
private url: string = '../assets/data/articulos.json';

getImages() {
  return this.visibleImages = IMAGES.slice(0);
}

getImage(id: number) {
  return IMAGES.slice(0).find(image => image.id === id);
}

}
const IMAGES = [
{..this is the array..} ];
```

This is the component with the image thumbnails here you can see all the thumbnails from the IMAGES array

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnChanges {
images: any[];
visibleImages: any[] = [];

constructor(private articulosService: ArticulosService) {
 this.visibleImages = this.articulosService.getImages();
}

ngOnChanges() {
 this.visibleImages = this.articulosService.getImages();
}
```

}

This is the image page component where you see the image title etc..

```
export class TutorialPostsComponent implements OnInit {
image:any

visibleImages: any[] = [];
constructor(private articulosService: ArticulosService, private route: 
ActivatedRoute) {
  this.visibleImages = this.articulosService.getImages();
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.image = this.articulosService.getImage(
  +this.route.snapshot.params['id']
);
}
}
```

Here I changed the service to fetch from a JSON instead of the hardcoded array

```
   export class ArticulosService {
   private _url: string = '../assets/data/articulos.json';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  getImages(): Observable<TutoGaleria[]> {
    return this._http.get<TutoGaleria[]>(this._url)
  }
  }
```

I can see the data in the thumbnails but this data is not passing for the image details as when I was using the array.

I think is related to the `getImage(id: number)` function I don't know how to do this part fetching from a JSON.

How can I do the same functionality with the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you were returning an array, but you now return an [Observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables).

That is a different type of data, and a whole programming paradigm: you are now not passing objects, but you are passign "events", that need to be handled.

the  `this.visibleImages = this.articulosService.getImages();` line is now working differently then you expect it, because you won't get the object you requre, but the **Observable** reference, which will give you the results *in the future*.

To understand this, I really recommend you read the linked tutorial. Your solutions will be something like this:

```
const getImagesSubscription = this.articulosService.getImages().subscribe(
  (response) =>  {this.visibleImages = response;},
  (error) => { << handle errors here >> },
  () => { << complete event here >> });
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetching data from a json file is asynchronous, so it's a bit different from getting your data from an array and you need to consider that.

Your service will look like something like that :

```
export class ArticulosService {
   private _url: string = '../assets/data/articulos.json';

   constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

   getImages(): Observable<TutoGaleria[]> {
      return this._http.get<TutoGaleria[]>(this._url)
   }

   getImage(id: string): Observable<TutoGaleria> {
      return this.getImages()
         .map(images => images.filter(image => image.id === id))
         .filter(images => images.length)
         .map(images => images[0])
   }
}
```

And your component :

```
export class TutorialPostsComponent implements OnInit {
    image:any
    visibleImages: any[] = [];

    constructor(private articulosService: ArticulosService, 
                private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.visibleImages = this.articulosService.getImages();
    }

    ngOnInit(){
         this.articulosService.getImage(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
              .subscribe(image => this.image = image);     
    }

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hello I tested this solution and doesn't work and give this errors:                                         
 - Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'string'.
 - Argument of type '(images: TutoGaleria[]) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: TutoGaleria[], index: numb
er) => boolean'.

Comment: I supposed your id was a string but it looks like it's a number. Don't take it to the word, adapt it to your data structure :)